# Custom combobox not working (Stackoverflow exception thrown)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Hi below is the code for the custom combobox I created in vb

```
Public Class DtsStepsComboBox
    Inherits Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    Private status As String
    Public Sub New()
        Me.DrawMode = Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
    End Sub
    Private Sub DtsStepsComboBox_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles Me.DrawItem
        Try
            e.DrawBackground()
            e.DrawFocusRectangle()
            Dim item As DtsStepsComboBoxItem
            Dim rectPoint As New System.Drawing.Point
            Dim textPoint As New System.Drawing.Point
            Dim stikedFont As Drawing.Font
            'stikedFont = CreateFont(e.Font.OriginalFontName, e.Font.Size, False, False, True)
            'Dim imageSize As New Size
            'imageSize = ListaImg1.ImageSize
            rectPoint.X = 1
            rectPoint.Y = 1

            Dim bounds As New System.Drawing.Rectangle
            bounds = e.Bounds
            Dim rectSize As New System.Drawing.Size
            rectSize.Height = bounds.Height - 2
            rectSize.Width = bounds.Width - 2
            textPoint.X = rectPoint.X + rectSize.Width + 2
            textPoint.Y = rectPoint.Y

            item = CType(Me.Items.Item(e.Index), DtsStepsComboBoxItem)

            If (item.status.Equals("0")) Then
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Drawing.Brushes.White, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(rectPoint, rectSize))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.text, e.Font, Drawing.Brushes.Black, textPoint)
            ElseIf (item.status.Equals("1")) Then
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Drawing.Brushes.Green, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(rectPoint, rectSize))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.text, e.Font, Drawing.Brushes.Black, textPoint)
            ElseIf (item.status.Equals("2")) Then
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Drawing.Brushes.Red, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(rectPoint, rectSize))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.text, e.Font, Drawing.Brushes.Black, textPoint)
            ElseIf (item.status.Equals("3")) Then
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Drawing.Brushes.White, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(rectPoint, rectSize))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.text, e.Font, Drawing.Brushes.Black, textPoint)
            ElseIf (item.status.Equals("4")) Then
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Drawing.Brushes.White, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(rectPoint, rectSize))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(item.text, e.Font, Drawing.Brushes.Black, textPoint)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have added the component to form and added objects to it using

```
 Dim tempItem As DtsStepsComboBoxItem
        tempItem = New DtsStepsComboBoxItem("This is of type 0", "0")
        sampleCombo.Items.Add(tempItem)
        tempItem = New DtsStepsComboBoxItem("This is of type 1", "1")
        sampleCombo.Items.Add(tempItem)
        tempItem = New DtsStepsComboBoxItem("This is of type 2", "2")
        sampleCombo.Items.Add(tempItem)
        tempItem = New DtsStepsComboBoxItem("This is of type 3", "3")
        sampleCombo.Items.Add(tempItem)
        tempItem = New DtsStepsComboBoxItem("This is of type 4", "4")
        sampleCombo.Items.Add(tempItem)
```

but when i run I get a stack overflow error on e.DrawBackground()

any ideas?

Comment: You might want to 1) remove C# tag 2) provide `DtsStepsComboBoxItem` class declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was calling MyBase.onDrawItem(e). Which went recursive I guess. There is no need for that call. Removing that fixed my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in your invoked method to understand what's making it call recursively. My bet is that your draw method is diring some event that, on the other hand, calls the method itself.

You might try to put a flag in the beginning of your method

```
private _drawing=false;

private method()
{
  if (_drawing) return; // do nothing
  try
  {
    _drawing=true;
    //call or paste your logic here
  }
  finally
  {
    _drawing=false
  }
}
```

this way your method will not call itself everlasting.

Comment: Sorry i put this in c#; only now i realized your code is in VB. Anyway i bet you understand its meaning